# Sql Dependency does not fire

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

Here's the example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
void Initialization()
{
    // Create a dependency connection.
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.

    // Create a new SqlCommand object.
    using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT ShipperID, CompanyName, Phone FROM dbo.Shippers", 
        connection))
    {

        // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
        SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);
        // Maintain the refence in a class member.

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange+=new
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        // Execute the command.
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}

// Handler method
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, 
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
{
  // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
}

void Termination()
{
    // Release the dependency.
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, queueName);
}
```

How would I use this code to setup SqlDependency in my console.

I tried putting in the start method the `Initialization' method, but it does not fire`SomeMethod`.

Also -- if it's possible -- I am looking to pass some arguments to my `SqlNotificationEventArgs` such as the rows.

Answer (score 0):

The `Initialization` method only opens a connection to the database server. The `Start` method actually registers a dependency using the `command`. Your program will need to call both.

`OnDependencyChange` will be fired when the query result of the aforementioned command changes.

If you look at the reference page for [`SqlNotificationEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), it does not tell you which rows have changed -- you'll have to query the database yourself to determine that.